# Error 550 occurred by deploying via MSdeploy.exe

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008, msdeploy

For ASP.NET project MSBuild gives some files in E:\Build such as:

- TestProjectA.deploy.cmd
- TestProjectA.SetParameters.xml
- TestProjectA.SourceManifest.xml
- TestProjectA.zip

To deploy from Windows 7 to Windows Server 2008 R2 (IIS 7)

Executing command gives following error message:

**Command**

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3>msdeploy.exe -verb:sync  -source:contentPath='E:\Build'  -dest:contentPath='ra/files-to-pub',ComputerName="https://<IP>:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=ra",UserName='DEV\Administrator',Password='MyPassword',AuthType='Basic' -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -whatif -allowUntrusted
```

**Error Message:**

`Info: Using ID 'd1bbee7a-e940-4be1-b41d-1847b3e7022d' for connections to the remote server.
Error Code: ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC
More Information: Could not connect to the remote computer ("[IP ADDRESS]") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.
Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.
Error: The remote server returned an error: (550).
Error count: 1`

Given link suggest to do:

- Ping the remote machine.  *STATUS-OK
- The msdepsvc or wmsvc service is started on the remote server. *STATUS-OK
- Firewall is not blocking incoming connections of your ports on the destination. If  it used the default installation, then it would be 80 for msdepsvc and 8172 for wmsvc. *STATUS-OK

Both of service are running at target server:

- Web Management Services
- Web Deployment Agent Service

What can do now to solve it?

Answer (score 24):

If you have checked the basic stuff like

- Credentials are correct
- [Website name is spelt correctly](http://www.benday.com/2013/07/12/fix-error_could_not_connect_to_remotesvc-error-using-visual-studio-2012-web-deploy/) everywhere

And have tried the steps mentioned [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/troubleshooting-web-deploy-problems-with-visual-studio)

And it still didn't work then may I suggest troubleshooting using [Web Management Service Failed Request Tracing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729439%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Solved by following command…… 

Configure IIS [Here](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/configure-the-web-deployment-handler)
....AND...
`C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3> msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package='E:\Test-MsDeploy\Package\TestProjectA.zip' -dest:auto,wmsvc='https://{IP}:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=Default%20Web%20Site',user‌​Name='******',password='******',includeAcls='False' -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile="E:\Test-MsDeploy\Package\TestProjectA.SetParameters.xml" -allowUntrusted`

Comment: Incorrect website name bit me. Simple fix. Pain to track down.

Comment: Yup Error 550 means that the site name to which you are publishing to does not exist on the service. Create an empty site on the web server with the exact same name and then publish again. It will work

Comment: Website name for me too. Name had changed from `www.sitename.com` to `sitename.com` in IIS. Had to remove `www.` in publish profile.

Answer (score 15):

This might be too late, but for others checking this error.  Verify the Site name too.  IE, Default Web Site/SiteDeploy (or whatever you call it)

k

Comment: this was it for me. not `SERVER/site-name`, just `site-name`